# Unable to merge an unallocated space in GParted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, disk, diskspace

I tried to allocate more disk space to ubuntu but I'm stuck here. When i try to resize/move the *swap partition* to occupy the unallocated space, it allows me to but not when i try that with *home or root*. **I have already tried turning swap off and deleteing it temporarily but it still wont allow me to resize home/root partition.**

Can someone please tell me the exact steps to follow?[image]

[image: Gparted Screenshot]